# Forms created in pardot not sending in leads

Tags: leads, landing-page, form, pardot

I have created a form in pardot and put it on landing page. Form completion actions are:

1. add to list
2. send autoresponder
3. add to crm campaign

first two things are happening however last one is not working. Nothing happens in leads in both pardot and SF.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the prospect to a user that is mapped to a n active Salesforce user? The lead will only be created in Salesforce if you assign it.